# Do we [stl] need [stl]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

> **Update:**
>
> STL synonym created instead of burnination: See [stl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stl)

It appears that [stl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stl) is "selectively" used for questions that utilize the Standard Template Library.  However, this only applies to C++, and such code should already make use of the STL.  Even if a C++ question doesn't utilize the STL for whatever reason, omitting this tag doesn't send any kind of signal.  With over 2000 [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and only 59 [stl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stl) questions, it hardly adds anything to the question.

[image]

Comment: `such code should already make use of the STL` unless [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] of-course, in which case it's acceptable to disregard most of the STL.

Comment: Not to mention that [the STL is not a thing anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5205571/2069064)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## NO, Do not Burninate the tag.

Make it a synonym of [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) instead. This is better than burnination because it makes it impossible to then re-create the tag, and it also guides people correctly when they try to use it.

Additionally, a mod can then "merge" the tag, which will essentially silently (without "bumping") edit the tag off all current questions (which is what a burnination does anyway).

Answer (score 4):

You have my vote to remove it. Firstly, it's actually a bit of a misnomer - the standard template library is actually an older library (architected mainly by Stepanov) that influenced the C++ standard library, which seems to have taken over the name. Secondly, I doubt many other languages have "standard library" as a tag. Finally, it's not all that descriptive - while not as large as the Java or Python standard libraries, there is a lot of stuff in the C++ standard library.

Comment: and, I would add, that the `stl` should be the `sl` because it is a lot mroe than just the template part..... but that's a different issue ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As long as all the question marked `STL` are already marked as `C++` I have no issue with that.

Comment: For the record, you can search: [`[stl] -[c++]`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stl%20-c%2b%2b)